# How to use SOQL Query as a report

Tags: soql, reporting

Let's say I have this query:
SELECT Id, Action, Section, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Display FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK

How can I use it as a report? I want to make a report about what users have made for the week.

Comment: Why do you need a report when you already have the query outputs? And what kind of report would you need? You mean a standard Salesforce report or something in an external system?

Comment: I need to make standard SF report for my colleagues. They want to press a few buttons and get report. Hence why I'm asking

Comment: As I said I want to make a report about what users have made for the week. In other words I want to make report about changes in classes, triggers, objects, fields, etc that user have made for the past week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a report in Salesforce, you have the limitation that Salesforce Reports don't run on configuration data (metadata), but only on actual data in the system (standard and custom objects).

Here's a possible solution:

1. create a custom object that has the fields you want to report on
   (e.g. SetupAuditTrailId, Action, Section, CreatedDate,
   CreatedBy.Name, Display)
2. create an apex batch job that runs every night, and executes the query above. Then saves the result onto the custom object (using SetupAuditTrailId as a unique identifier so you make sure you don't
   create duplicate values)
3. create a report on the custom object for your users (or enable them to create their own reports)